# Get records of specific month or date from datetimepicker value to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures

I want to get all records from a SQL Server database; I am using Entity Framework and C#.

I am using a `DateTimePicker` value to passed to the stored procedure, and the stored procedure is expecting for datetime object when I pick data from datetime picker it get whole string but I need only date. I tried with datetime object but no success place that value to datetime object dt

Now the problem is that when I try to change format of datetimepicker it convert it to string but I need datetime obj but only with date

```
 DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dbobj.sp_Select_Expense_Month(dt).ToList();
```

How to pass something to stored procedure? Please help me 
lot of prayers for all commentators

I have tried many solution but the closest was with like query in a stored procedure but it didn't show any results but headers called in gridview and even when I tried that in SQL Server Management Studio it show same thing columns name without any record

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Select_Expense_Month
    @dt dateTime
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Expense 
    WHERE [DateTime] LIKE '@dt%'
END
GO
```

in database structure its type of date only

Comment: What's the date format you are passing?

Comment: Cant you pass SqlDbType.DateTime to Stored Procedure ?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: i am using datetime in sql  @at-2016

Comment: See the given answers. That will do the trick.

Comment: i am just beginner plz make more clear about sqldbtype  how to try that what should i check .@vivek nuna

Comment: First try to pass a default date like this - `WHERE CONVERT(DATE, [DateTime]) = CONVERT(DATE, '2016-10-16')`. See if this works. Then you think to pass dynamic values. That would be better.

Answer (score 3):

You can trim the `time` from `datetime` even in `sql`

```
SELECT * FROM Expense WHERE [DateTime] = cast(@dt as date)
```

Make sure you pass valid datetime format

Comment: @NajamIslam pass it as datetime